# Python 3 urllib.request send cookie, fetch results

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, urllib

I am trying to retrieve the 2nd page of these results:

http://raceresults.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=451

If I click on page 2 at the bottom, it goes to the 2nd page, but the URL stays the same. If I look at the http headers I can see this cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: sportstats_preferences="{\"raceId\":451,\"firstRow\":40,
\"category\":\"All Categories\",\"chronosStep\":\"INSTRUCTIONS
\",\"facebookLoggedIn\":false,\"twitterLoggedIn\":false,\"fbServiceId
\":0,\"twServiceId\":0,\"unit\":1}"; Version=1; Max-Age=2592000; 
Expires=Sat, 04-Apr-2015 14:30:28 GMT
```

I can see this is different than the first page in that `firstRow` is being set to `40`.

I am attempting to get this 2nd page in Python 3 with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
cookie = 'sportstats_preferences="{{\\"raceId\\":451,\\"firstRow\\":40,\\"category\\":\\"All Categories\\",\\"chronosStep\\":\\"INSTRUCTIONS\\",\\"facebookLoggedIn\\":false,\\"twitterLoggedIn\\":false,\\"fbServiceId\\":0,\\"twServiceId\\":0,\\"unit\\":1}}"; Version=1; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Sat, 04-Apr-2015 04:18:36 GMT'
opener.addheaders = [('Cookie', cookie)]
f = opener.open(url).read().decode("utf-8")
for line in f.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

But that still just returns the results from the first page. Am I going about this the right way? Any ideas how I can get the results of the 2nd page?

Comment: I also noticed that if I click the 2nd page and view source, I still see data from the first page. But if I refresh the page it will then show me page 2 results in the source. I tried opening the URL twice in my code, but that didn't help.

Comment: they have a view state in the page (in `<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState"...>`, see page source) that I think is used by the server to decide which page to show.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option may be to use Selenium and the corresponding python package.  Selenium allows you to use python to open and automatically control a web browser.  This would allow you to interact with their next page buttons, and read the results in a python script.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's not what I was hoping to hear. Selenium looks heavy and complicated.

Comment: @user3449833 If the website actually gave you a different address to retrieve, or a text version, it would obviously be easier.  You might be surprised how easy it is to use Selenium to control firefox.  Look at the examples in the second link.  All you have to do is tell Selenium what buttons you would press if you were manually browsing.  Selenium itself will just control firefox based on your python package commands.

Comment: I'm on headless Linux, so that doesn't help, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I've got it grabbing the first page ok, but I can't figure out how to "click". If I find an element using: browser.find_element_by_id('mainForm:j_idt294') , it just hangs if I add .click(). Any ideas?

Comment: I can't test any of this on my computer, but try the method here: http://www.pythoneye.com/304_19734831/ - but find your element the same way you already did.